# C++ std::begin(c) for vs 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I need to use `std::begin`/`end` in vs 2008.
I get:

> 'begin' : is not a member of 'std' when I try to compile. Are there any solution?

Comment: Did you include `<iterator>` ?

Comment: I need to use vs 2008 cause, I have a lib compiled in vs 2008 and it is not compatible with newest version of vs (i don't have the lib source).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::begin`/`std::end` have been introduce in C++11, if your compiler is too old to support it, you may upgrade your compiler or implement your own functions:

For C-array:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
T* begin(T (&a)[N]) { return a; }

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
T* end(T (&a)[N]) { return a + N; }
```

Comment: @WeekUp: Create a new file *stdc++11.h* (or similar), copy paste code there, and include the file in each file which uses `std::begin`/`end`. You will have to remove `std::` from the code, (or putting the given code inside `namespace std` (but it is UB))

Comment: Jarod42 I solve, it don't work because I forget to include the header where I paste this. Thanks again !!